# Debugging a Sentiment Analyzer

Tags: python, nltk, data-analysis, sentiment-analysis, data-science

I'm attempting my first shot at NLP using Python's NLTK module to run a sentiment analysis on select tweets. I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/twitter-sentiment-analysis-using-python-and-nltk/) and have downloaded the [Sentiment140 Tweet Corpus](http://help.sentiment140.com/for-students/) as my training data set since this is for educational purposes only (contains ~1.6m hand classified tweets).

My code can be found [here](https://bpaste.net/show/2c4f9274d413). Please note that this is being done in Python 2, in an iPython Notebook.

**Question Part 1**
I'm testing my code with 10,000 rows from the training set to see if it works before feeding it all 1.6m rows. When I run the code, line 96 returns None:

```
print classifier.show_most_informative_features(32)
Most Informative Features
None
```

However, the tutorial suggests I should see something like the following:

```
Most Informative Features
contains(not) = False          positi : negati =      1.6 : 1.0
contains(tired) = False          positi : negati =      1.2 : 1.0
contains(excited) = False          negati : positi =      1.2 : 1.0
contains(great) = False          negati : positi =      1.2 : 1.0
contains(looking) = False          positi : negati =      1.2 : 1.0
contains(like) = False          positi : negati =      1.2 : 1.0
contains(love) = False          negati : positi =      1.2 : 1.0
contains(amazing) = False          negati : positi =      1.2 : 1.0
contains(enemy) = False          positi : negati =      1.2 : 1.0
contains(about) = False          negati : positi =      1.2 : 1.0
contains(best) = False          negati : positi =      1.2 : 1.0
contains(forward) = False          positi : negati =      1.2 : 1.0
contains(friend) = False          negati : positi =      1.2 : 1.0
contains(horrible) = False          positi : negati =      1.2 : 1.0
```

I'm using line 96 as an indicator to tell me whether or not the classifier works. In terms of fixes that I've already tried: I saw a comment in the tutorial that suggested line 87 should be:

```
training_set = nltk.classify.util.apply_features(extract_features, tweets)
```

instead of what it currently is:

```
training_set = nltk.classify.apply_features(extract_features, tweets)
```

I tried both of these variations.

I'd like to iron this out before I run the full 1.6m row data set through to train the classifier.

Here are all of my import statements for the notebook (some import statements are used in other areas of the notebook):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from pandas.tseries.resample import TimeGrouper
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import FreqDist
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import subjectivity
from nltk.sentiment import SentimentAnalyzer
import nltk.sentiment.util
import csv
import re
import networkx as nx
import time
%matplotlib inline
%pylab inline
```

**Question Part 2**
How do I tweak this code to return the polarity scores themselves. Something like:

```
compound: -0.6759, neg: 0.41, neu: 0.59, pos: 0.0
```

Based on [this NLTK page](http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html), it seems like I would call the .polarity_socres() method, but I'm not sure where in my code I'd even do that. Here is their code that returns the above:

```
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
for sentence in sentences:
    print(sentence)
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
    for k in sorted(ss):
        print('{0}: {1}, '.format(k, ss[k]), end='')
```